# Wiring a light switch and power outlet independent from each other

Tags: wiring, lighting, switch, receptacle

I just bought a light switch and power outlet in a single box. I've wired it following the instructions, but it doesn't work the way I want it to work.
When the light switch is turned off and a power plug is plugged in, my light turns on half-half.
When the light switch is turned on, the power outlet doesn't give any power.

I have used Wago connectors at the red junctions.
[image: Wiring diagram]

Comment: What do you mean by "my light turns on half-half"?

Comment: Did you replace an existing switch with this new switch/combo box in an effort to put an outlet where the switch is?

Comment: Where are you on this planet, and can you post photos of the wiring involved?

Comment: I cannot understand what your house wiring looks like at the switch junction box. What wires enter the box and how were they attached to the switch that was there before?

Comment: if you've wired it like that and it behaves like that you don't have enough wires in the box.